# Selenium Server and Chromedriver doesn't work on Linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I have a Selenium Standalone Server on my local machine (MAC), and it works fine every time I run a test (WebdriverIO).

```
09:27:06.951 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--headless",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--window-size=1024,768",
      "--no-sandbox"
    ]
  }
}
09:27:06.962 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8) on port 42652
Only local connections are allowed.
09:27:08.168 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
09:27:08.314 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 3a6c1206b6cd99a762007069868cad2f (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
09:27:19.053 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session 3a6c1206b6cd99a762007069868cad2f (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Now, I am trying to move the selenium server to a Linux machine. I configured and installed all the necessary packages. However, the test just hanged.

**Selenium log from Linux machine**

```
[dnguyen@test tmp]$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
09:24:02.305 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
09:24:02.373 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-05-03 09:24:02.413:INFO::main: Logging initialized @289ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
09:24:02.604 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
09:24:02.697 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
09:24:16.387 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--headless",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--window-size=1024,768",
      "--no-sandbox"
    ]
  }
}
09:24:16.388 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.7 (efcef9a3ecda02b2132af215116a03852d08b9cb) on port 29488
Only local connections are allowed.
[1556889856.409][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=0: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
[1556889856.714][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=0: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
09:24:16.791 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
09:24:17.078 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session 86ea9b4bd11c3d2d8a994e893440087e (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

**Log from WebdriverIO**

```
Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/path-to-test.js)
```

It doesn't have that error when I run on my local machine. Not sure what is the different between Selenium Server on MAC and Linux.

**Updated**: The 443 port on the Linux server doesn't open, so it cannot reach the site. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The 443 port on the Linux server doesn't open, so it cannot reach the site. That's all.

If you are in the same situation, you can try to use **WGET** to reach the site first.